# How to print array values without array key

Tags: php, arrays, api, foreach, drupal-7

I am working in API with JSON output for products list by using Core PHP, here i need some correction in my output. I just want 'body','dishes' and 'dish_details' in array keys and dont want to show product id's 18,26,etc.. as array key.

If i remove `[$nid]` from my loop, then it prints last product details only.

See my code in below:

```
foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_title'] =  $node->title;
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_image'] =  $node->field_recipe_entities[$node->field_recipe]->field_recipe_image_url;
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_price'] =  $node->field_recipe_entities[$node->field_recipe]->commerce_price_formatted;
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_rating'] =  $node->rating;
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_desc'] =  $node->desc;
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_type'] =  $node->type;
    $output['dishes'][$nid]['dish_details']['dish_location'] =  $node->location;
}

$return = new stdClass();
$return->body = $output;
$return->message = "Dish list retrieved successfully.";
$return->error = 'nil';
$return->status = 200;
```

and see my output:

```
{
  "body":{
     "dishes":{
        "18":{
           "dish_details":{
              "dish_id":"18",
              "product_id":"25",
              "dish_title":"Cogo Laoreet Roto",
              "dish_image":"http://localhost/drupal739/sites/default/files/dish_images/ima7070.tmp.png",
              "dish_price":"189.53  INR",
              "dish_rating":"",
              "dish_desc":{
                 "value":"Capto luctus nobis oppeto pagus torqueo veniam. Dolore eros hendrerit. Consectetuer genitus iaceo quia sed. Caecus commoveo dignissim elit melior modo refoveo tego vicis.\n\n",
                 "summary":null,
                 "format":"full_html",
                 "safe_value":"<p>Capto luctus nobis oppeto pagus torqueo veniam. Consectetuer genitus iaceo quia sed. Caecus commoveo dignissim elit melior modo refoveo tego vicis.</p>\n",
                 "safe_summary":""
              },
              "dish_type":"",
              "dish_location":""
           }
        },
        "26":{
           "dish_details":{
              "dish_id":"26",
              "product_id":"8",
              "dish_title":"Obruo Quibus",
              "dish_image":null,
              "dish_price":"500.00  INR",
              "dish_rating":"",
              "dish_desc":{
                 "value":"Amet aptent brevitas caecus commoveo consequat populus si. Distineo dolor esca gemino importunus metuo paratus tincidunt wisi.\n\n",
                 "summary":null,
                 "format":"full_html",
                 "safe_value":"<p>Amet aptent brevitas caecus commoveo consequat populus si. Distineo dolor esca gemino importunus metuo paratus tincidunt wisi.</p>\n",
                 "safe_summary":""
              },
              "dish_type":"",
              "dish_location":""
           }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any solution please share here.

Comment: is this json format?? i doubt.

Comment: yeah its JSON format output only

Comment: What I think about this should print something like
"dishes":{
       "dish_details":{
              "dish_title" {
                      object values here

Comment: Yes i want to print like that

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are iterating through foreach you need to give the index to each node so they don't override the values.

Weather you specify the index in the beginning of the array or at the middle

```
$ouput[]['dishes']['anotherindex']['title'] = value;
```

which will print something like

```
0 : {
  "dishes" : {
      "anotherindex" : {
           "title" : {
              values here
```

Comment: Yeah but prints only last loop value..i need all values in a loop

Comment: @Bharathi06  Actually you are overriding keys values and you get only the last row..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.5 and you want to search for a specific element then you can use the following without a loop:

```
//If 18 is one of the dishes key
$key = array_search('18', array_column($data['body'], 'dishes'));

if ($key !== false) {
    //Do something with that array segment
    var_dump($data['body'][$key]);
}
```